# Share CMS for both website and iOS app

Tags: html, ios, wordpress, content-management-system

Basically I have a client who wants to create a simple website that has regularly updated content and iOS app that pulls the same information into the app. So they don't have to enter it twice.

I would prefer to not HTML scrape so I was thinking of using the Wordpress CMS to create the site and their API to pull the information for the app. As they are not very knowledgeable with computers so I figured this would be a good solution.

Can anyone advise a smarter / better solution to this problem? or will I run into any issues with using Wordpress for this function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've probably considered this, but just to be sure.  Is there a reason that the iOS app needs to be a true app, and not just a mobile view of the same CMS?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with a client to do the exact same thing except with an ASP.NET CMS. I used AJAX/JSON with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for the communication and created the application using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

As of right now, I have not had any problems. Although, I'm not sure of any issues you might have if your going to be developing your app using Objective-C (pure native).

Since your playing with Wordpress, you might also want to consider this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220135/973155